# Adding OAuth 2.0 authentication to a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I have an API that requires authentication via OAuth 2.0. I originally anticipated using [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle), however from investigation this is more to do with hooking up 3rd parties into Symfony's security/auth mechanism and does not provide the required mechanism for validating OAuth 2.0 `Authorization` headers.

I then found some information about [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) which enables an application to become it's own OAuth 2.0 provider as well as providing the required security mechanisms to validate `Authorization` headers.

However the problem is that I would like integrate the OAuth 2.0 provider (authorisation server) in an external application (which contains the user base) and not include it within the API. Which will provide some mechanism for performing the token verification against this external app via (another) RESTful API.

**Points:**

- RESTful API requires OAuth 2.0 authentication.
- OAuth 2.0 authorisation server to be situated in a separate application.

I feel I should use [*Implicit*](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) grant and call the authorization server on each request to validate that the token is correct.

[image]

[image]

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: so If I understand correctly, you want to authenticate by using user credentials from an external API?

Comment: Not user credentials. Via oauth but that is external to the API. All examples i have seen have had them together

Comment: So you want to setup FOSOAuthServerBundle in your current application so that an external app can use your application to authenticate against?

Comment: I want to setup the OAuth provider on a different app, but have the REST API provide OAuth authentication against this provider.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible.  What's the use case?

Comment: Its def possible and a valid case... Why should the auth server and resource server be the same?  Im building an api that requires auth against another apps user base and OAuth is the mechanism we wish to provide auth by. I was hoping that there exists some solution already but sounds like ill have to adapt existing things.

Comment: maybe have a look at [how to create a custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html).  I have used an external api for logging in to an application like this, but never used an external api to login to my api.  maybe this can get you on the right path

Comment: I think I will have to create a custom user provider for the RESTful authentication of Tokens that reside in another database. But perhaps striping out some of the authentication logic from FOSOAuthServerBundle since having a nicely integrated solution with Symfony would be good too.

Comment: I'm interested in your question, did you end up getting this to work?

Comment: @Sehael I ended up going with a listener which checks for for presents of the `Authorization` header and validates this bearer token against an external database returning the username which then is looked up in a custom user provider which is based off the cookbooks WebService user provider. I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Any news on this? Do you now if there is any bundle with this logic already implemented? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As far as I undesratnd your requirement, you require to authenticate your APIs via external OAuth Authorization Server:

- Client needs to provide the access token retrieved in the above steps
  along with the request to access the protected resource. Access token
  will be sent as an authorization parameter in the request header.
- Server will authenticate the request based on the token.
- If token is valid then client will get an access to protected resource otherwise access is denied.

here is an [example](http://www.e-zest.net/blog/rest-authentication-using-oauth-2-0-resource-owner-password-flow-protocol/) which might help you to achieve your requirement. Check this [document](http://www.hsc.com/Portals/0/Uploads/Articles/WP_Securing_RESTful_WebServices_OAuth2635406646412464000.pdf) .

Or simply, you can do with [Jersey and Oauth](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/OAuth)

Also, you can check [Apache Oltu](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Documentation) and figure out the way to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the big companies like Google, Facebook etc have a separate authorization server from the API server. Check out Google's OAuth authorization flow below [image: Google OAuth Authorization]

You can also check Google's [OAuth Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) for the details.

So all you would need to do is implement a OAuth Provider so that you can authorize against that provider. There's a list of libraries available on the OAuth website: http://oauth.net/code. You can specifically look [here](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/); there is an example for running an OAuth Service Provider in Java.

Answer (score 2):

oAuth can most definitely be a server other than your application server. Below is a picture of what the authentication sequence would look like:

[image]

-- Obviously, if the forum can't decode or validate the token, the forum would return a 401 status code instead of a 200 status code.

As long as your oAuth server & the Forum share the same public key, you're more than okay with splitting your oAuth Server & your application.

In fact, take a look at [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/). Paste the token you get from the oAuth server into there. It should be able to decode the token right away. Then, you can put your public key into the 'secret' text box to verify the token is verified.

Your application (Forum, in this example) should be able to do the same:

1) Grab the token from the Authorization header of the request

2) Decode the token

3) Check the expire date

4) Verify the token using the oAuth's public key

5) Return successful status code or a failure status code

Comment: I've not looked into JWT for this implementation but I guess this is something that can be considered. Thanks!